# My BeagleBone Black does not turn on other than power LED turns on for a second

Tags: microcontroller, raspberry-pi, linux

The power LED just turns on for a second and turns off. I again tried with power adapter (5V 1A) and the mini USB cable but nothing else happens.

Comment: you have anything plugged into it.  what if you unplug everything and then plug power in?

Answer (score 1):

It is probably a power issue, or rather the lack of current. Try the following, or a combination thereof:

- New USB cable
- New power adapter
- A different USB port
- A different PC/Laptop
- A different OS (Windows/OS X/Linux) - I have had issues where some boards work with Windows, but *not at all* with Mac - especially if it is a (Chinese) clone.

See also [Element14 branded beaglebone black won't power-on](https://www.element14.com/community/thread/41564/l/element14-branded-beaglebone-black-wont-power-on?displayFullThread=true). From there there are two getting started links:

- [Troubleshooting](http://beagleboard.org/getting-started#troubleshooting), and;
- [BeagleBone Getting Started](http://inspire.logicsupply.com/p/beaglebone-getting-started_3.html)

When you plug the BBB into your computer's USB port does it appear to be listed in the machines USB devices? According to the *Getting Started* guide:

> The first time you plug in the BeagleBone it will appear as a 'USB thumb drive' with the required drivers in the Driver folder (Windows, Mac OSX and Linux versions). (takes about 20 seconds)